# Getting a Dictionary into a CSV form using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of files that I have iterated over and made a dictionary of a Keyword: file name, phrase. I want to output to a csv files that will look like this

** sample of dictionary created**

```
{'BatMan': [('1.txt', 'I am Bat-Man'),
         ('2.txt', 'Bat-man is awesome')],
 'Flash': [('1.txt', 'The Flash is awesome'),
         ('1.txt', ' The Flash is only in txt 1 though'),]}
```

I set this dict to my dictionary and have the following code

```
my_dict= dict(**out)
with open('MYTESTER.csv', 'wb') as f: 

    wcsv = csv.writer(f) 
    wcsv.writerow([ 'word', 'context'])
    for key, value in my_dict.items():
        wcsv.writerow( [key, value] )
```

Word    Context
Bat-Man 1.txt, I am Bat-Man
Bat-Man 2.txt, Bat-man is awesome
Flash   1.txt, 'The Flash is awesome
Flash   1.txt,  The Flash is only in txt 1 though

But what I'm getting is
Word    Context
Bat-Man 1.txt, I am Bat-Man , 2.txt, Bat-man is awesome
Flash   1.txt, 'The Flash is awesome , 1.txt, The Flash is only in txt 1 though

I'm sure this is a simple mistake somewhere in how I specify writerow but I've been looking through the documentation and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Why is it printing it like this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this is happening is because you are trying to stick a multi-dimensional list into a single csv cell.  When this happens, the csv module doesn't know what to do, so it just prints the entry out as a string.  To fix this, you will have to add another column and incorporate two for loops.  One is for the dictionary key:value pair and the other is for the tuple items in the dictionary value.

Please try out the example script below:

```
with open("MYTESTER.csv", "wb") as f:
    wcsv = csv.writer(f)
    wcsv.writerow(['word', 'context', 'text'])
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        for item in value: 
            wcsv.writerow([key, item[0], item[1]])
```

This will produce a csv file that looks like this:

```
word,   context,    text
BatMan, 1.txt,  I am Bat-Man
BatMan, 2.txt,  Bat-man is awesome
Flash,  1.txt,  The Flash is awesome
Flash,  1.txt,   The Flash is only in txt 1 though
```

This dictionary has a minimum of three items per row, thus three columns are needed to store it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need **two** `for` loops:

- one `for` loop for the dictionary items.
- one `for` loop for each different item in the list.